# JqxWidgets: Export nested grid

Tags: grid, nested, export-to-excel, jqxwidgets

While working with JqxWidges I met a problem with exporting nested grids which use one JSON as a source file. The common solution doesn't work. Actually it exports only parent grid colums.

```
   $("#excelExport").click(function () {
        $("#jqxGrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', chartName + ' ' + date);     
   });
```

One of the existing solutions (http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/reply/reply-to-export-data-from-a-nested-grid-13/) propose to push nested rows into data array while calling initrowdetails function.

Yes it works! But only for nested grids and in case when this grid was selected.

Answer (score 2):

So, from this step I am moving to next aproach:

1. To collect all necessary data into array using initial JSON (prevent you from gathering only separate selected data);
2. To initialise parent grid columns with all existing data and mark nested columns as hidden. Then when export don't forget to add true parameter to export both non/hidden columns;
3. Use standard export with custom array parameter;

That's it!

Data collecting:

```
var toExport = data.allClientsCountChart;
            var exp = new Array();

            for(var i in toExport){   
                var client = {};
                var countr = toExport[i].countries;
                client[labels.clientType]=toExport[i].clientType;
                client[labels.clientTypeCount]=toExport[i].clientTypeCount;
                exp.push(client);
                for(var j in countr) {   
                    var country = {}
                    var detailes = countr[j].clientDetails;
                    country[labels.countryType]=countr[j].countryType;
                    country[labels.clientsNumber]=countr[j].clientsNumber;
                    exp.push(country);
                    for(var d in detailes) {
                        var det = {}
                        det[labels.scriptName]=detailes[d].scriptName;
                        det[labels.clientsCount]=detailes[d].clientsCount;
                        exp.push(det);

                    }
                }

            }
```

Export:

```
$("#excelExport").click(function () {  

    $("#jqxGrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'csv', chartName + ' ' + date, true, exp, true);        

   }
```

And don't forget to set the fifth pafameter into true to export hidden columns.

No doubds, it looks hardcoded. But it works for me.

So, if you have a good solution - please leave a comment!!!